# How can I pass property getter as a function type to another function

Tags: properties, kotlin, getter

How can I pass property getter to a function that accepts function type?

Here is an example of what I want achieve:

```
class Test {
    val test: String
        get() = "lol"

    fun testFun(func: ()->String) {
        // invoke it here
    }

    fun callTest() {
        testFun(test::get) 
        // error: Type mismatch: inferred type is 
        // KFunction1<@ParameterName Int, Char> but () -> String was expected
    }
}
```

Is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reference the getter by writing `::test` (or `this::test`).

When you write `test::get`, you are actually referencing the `get` method on `String`. That method takes an index and returns the character at that index.

If the property was a `var` and you want a reference to its setter, you can write `::test::set`.

For more info on property references, see here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#bound-function-and-property-references-since-11

Comment: While this is true, I still don't see why bother with all of those complications, when you are getting the result of expression written in getter by just accessing variable by it's name

Comment: @GeorgySavatkov What if you do not want to deal with the value immediately, but at some later point, maybe never?

Comment: as a side-note: you can also access the variable using `this::test`. Maybe that makes it more obvious what's behind the reference ;-)

Comment: @Roland how's that relevant? What do you mean by dealing later?

Comment: I think the sample code is not the best to show the benefit of such a construct... If I understood you correctly, you question the usage of the reference instead of accessing the value directly... right?

Comment: @Roland I am questioning that there is any need for reflection for such a simple job like OP stated

Comment: Very good answer! It's exactly what I wanted. I didn't want to immediately access the value, but pass it to another object that will call this function numerous times, as the value can change over time, and I want it to be always the newest one. Thanks :)

Comment: @GeorgySavatkov Actually these are "just" references and I guess that they are as cheap to execute as their Java counterpart is (even if its technique may differ)... Otherwise such references wouldn't make sense at all and shouldn't be supported in the first place ;-)

Comment: @GeorgySavatkov but at least I got your point better now... would really be interesting if `{ test }` is the way to go or whether `::test` is equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, you can use `this::test` to refer to the getter. Alternatively, if you have `kotlin-reflect`, you can do `this::test.getter`.

When you pass the field as a function, it assumes you mean the getter. As a result, if you want the setter, you have two options:

```
this::test::set
```

or

```
this::test.setter
```

The latter, just like `this::test.getter` requires `kotlin-reflect`, or the program will crash (tested locally with Kotlin 1.2.50)

You can, however, get the getter in another way. But I recommend you just stick with `this::test` because it's shorter.

You can do:

```
this::something::get
```

With just `something::get` it refers to the method inside the String class, which returns a char at an index. For reference, the method declaration:

```
public override fun get(index: Int): Char
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind, just use `{ test }` (e.g. `testFun { test }`). This will exactly translate to your `() -> String`. The next best alternative is probably `::test` (or `this::test`) as was already mentioned.

The second has probably only minor (negligible?) impact on performance. I did not test it myself, nor did I found any source which tells something regarding it. The reason why I say this, is how the byte code underneath looks like. Just due to this question I asked myself about the difference of the two: [Is the property reference (::test) equivalent to a function accessing the property ({ test }) when passed as argument e.g. `() -> String`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51842043/is-test-equivalent-to-test-when-passed-to-string)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are doing something wrong on logical level.

If you are overriding `get` method of a variable, then you can access it's value through this get method. Thus, why bother with `test::get` (which is totally different method, by the way, all you are doing is trying to access `char` from `string`), when you can just access variable by it's name?