# Is the property reference (::test) equivalent to a function accessing the property ({ test }) when passed as argument e.g. `() -> String`?

Tags: kotlin

I started wondering whether accessing a property via `::test` is equivalent to calling `{ test }` or whether it is rather an indirect call using reflection.

The question came to my mind when looking at the following: [How can I pass property getter as a function type to another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51840809/how-can-i-pass-property-getter-as-a-function-type-to-another-function)

While both `::test` and `{ test }` work, the IDE (Intellij) set the `::test` to a `KProperty`-type whereas the latter type was `() -> String` when assigned to a variable. So there is a difference here. But what would be the effective difference? Are these real method references as in Java or are they rather a reflection way to access properties? Will one variant probably have any performance impact over the other?

Code snippet:

```
class Test(val test : String) {
  fun testFun(func: ()->String) : String = func()
  fun callTest() {
    testFun { test } // or (::test) // is it using reflection? are these real references?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think in this case it's better to check the bytecode to see what's going on.

I used the following code:

```
class Test(val test: String) {
    fun testFun(func: () -> String): Unit = TODO()
    fun callTest() {
        testFun { test }
        testFun(::test)
    }
}
```

For `testFun { test }` here's the generated bytecode:

```
ALOAD 0
NEW Test$callTest$1
DUP
ALOAD 0
INVOKESPECIAL Test$callTest$1.<init> (LTest;)V
CHECKCAST kotlin/jvm/functions/Function0
INVOKEVIRTUAL Test.testFun (Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;)V
```

And here's the bytecode for `testFun(::test)`:

```
ALOAD 0
NEW Test$callTest$2
DUP
ALOAD 0
CHECKCAST Test
INVOKESPECIAL Test$callTest$2.<init> (LTest;)V
CHECKCAST kotlin/jvm/functions/Function0
INVOKEVIRTUAL Test.testFun (Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;)V
```

They look almost exactly the same, except that the first one is creating a `Test$callTest$1`, while the second is using a `Test$callTest$2`. There's also an extra `CHECKCAST Test` in the second "version" because `Test$callTest$2` is expecting an instance of `Test` in its constructor.

So, what's the difference between `$1` and `$2`?

Here's `$1` version:

```
final class Test$callTest$1 extends kotlin/jvm/internal/Lambda implements kotlin/jvm/functions/Function0  {

    ....

    final synthetic LTest; this$0 // reference to your Test instance

    <init>(LTest;)V {
        ALOAD 0
        ALOAD 1
        PUTFIELD Test$callTest$1.this$0 : LTest;
        ALOAD 0
        ICONST_0 // Lambda arity is zero
        INVOKESPECIAL kotlin/jvm/internal/Lambda.<init> (I)V
        RETURN
    }

    public final String invoke() {
        ALOAD 0
        GETFIELD Test$callTest$1.this$0 : LTest;
        INVOKEVIRTUAL Test.getTest ()Ljava/lang/String;
    }
}
```

While `$2`:

```
final class Test$callTest$2 extends kotlin/jvm/internal/PropertyReference0  {

    ...

    <init>(LTest;)V {
        ALOAD 0
        ALOAD 1
        INVOKESPECIAL kotlin/jvm/internal/PropertyReference0.<init> (Ljava/lang/Object;)V
        RETURN
   }

    public Object get() {
        GETFIELD Test$callTest$2.receiver : Ljava/lang/Object;
        CHECKCAST Test
        INVOKEVIRTUAL Test.getTest ()Ljava/lang/String;
        ARETURN
    }
}
```

So it seems there's no big difference in terms of bytecode instructions.

EDIT:
Class `$2` inherits an `invoke` method from its parent class `PropertyReference0` that calls its `get()` method, while `$1` immediately declares `invoke`. Because of that, without further optimization `$2` performs one extra method call compared to `$1`.

Comment: Great explanation.

Comment: So we actually get a lot of code / functionality baked into the byte code when using `::test` (all the reflection stuff), but the relevant code seems to be as efficient as without reflection.

Comment: @Roland I just updated my answer. I think the main difference is in the extra method call that needs to be done in case of reflection, but probably it could be optimized with external tools like Proguard, making the performance equivalent between the 2 solutions. When in doubt I'd go with the more readable one.

Comment: That was my thought too... but in this specific case they are both similarly readable to me and just wanted to know which other impacts such a decision might have. For me such an impact is negligible.